How to center a bordered h1 element at the top of a webpage?
I'm trying to wrap my title at the top of my webpage with a border.
But, whenever I do, the text and the border around it shift all the way to the left of the webpage.
I'm trying to do this with an h1 element. I also don't want to just put a margin value to center it because it then will not scale with different webpage sizes.


#title {
  color: rgb(226, 35, 35);
  display: inline;
}

.borderedTitle {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.lato-bold {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}
<span class="borderedTitle">
  <h1 id="title" class="lato-bold">Title</h1>
</span>



I've tried different things like text-align: center, align-content: center, etc.

Side-note: A span as an inline element can not contain a block-level element such as a h1.

@tacoshy Invalid HTML is never a side note.

You don't even need a wrapper. You can horizontally center a block-level element by giving it a margin-left and margin-right of 0 such as using margin: 0 auto. All you need to do is limit the width of the block-level element to the content by using: width: max-content


#title {
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: rgb(226, 35, 35);
}
<h1 id="title">Title</h1>



If you want to use a container you can even make use of text-align:


.borderedTitle {
  text-align: center;
}

#title {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: rgb(226, 35, 35);
}
<div class="borderedTitle">
  <h1 id="title" class="lato-bold">Title</h1>
</div>




Try this:


body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start; /* Aligns the content at the top */
    height: 100vh; /* Ensure the body takes up the full viewport height */
    margin: 0;
}

.borderedTitle {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

#title {
    color: rgb(226, 35, 35);
    display: inline-block;
}

.lato-bold {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}
<div class="borderedTitle">
    <h1 id="title" class="lato-bold">Title</h1>
</div>




You add a lot of things that is unecessary and a bad practice. You should nearly never add display: flex to the body and if you do, then you most likely want to use flex-direction: column to maintain the normal block-level stacking behavior. align-items: flex-start is redundant and not needed. body should also nearly never have height: 100vh but min-height as otherwise you cause an unintended overflow. You don't need a wrapper if you add a flexbox to the body which causes everything to horizontally center (which also is a reason why the flexbox to the body is a very poor approach).

You also don't need to use inline-block as flexbox will calculate the width of child elements to their content on its own.
